# How to use python3.6 to extract filename from nautilus GUI when mouse pointer clicks on a file?

Tags: python, mouseevent, nautilus

I would like to write a nautilus script using python3.6 that will extract the name of a file from nautilus when the file is clicked on by the mouse pointer. Which python module can I use, or how do I write such a script from scratch?

For this script to be executable, I will make the script to start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Beyond that, I will need advice on how to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** I created the python script as shown below and saved it in folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/script` with a filename (here I called `myscript.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
from os import environ

a = Path('/home/user/tmp/name.txt')
paths = environ['NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS'].splitlines()
for p in paths:
    a.write_text(p)
```

**Step 2:** I had to make the `myscript.py` executable with this terminal command:

```
$ chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/myscript.py
```